# If you change the value of a cell , you must change the value of the TableView . How to implement it in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

If you change the value of a cell , you must change the value of the TableView . How to implement it in JavaFX?

```
public class Earnings implements List3{

  private ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

     private int a = 5;
     private int b = 5;
     private int c = a * b;

  @Override
  public void add(Person person) {
      personList.add( person );
  }
  public ObservableList<Person> getPersonList(){
      return personList;
  }

  public  void print (){
      int number = 0;
      System.out.println();
      for (Person person:personList){
          number++;
          System.out.println(number+")id ="+ person.getId()+"; position = "+person.getPosition()+"; salary = "+person.getSalary()+" prize = "+person.getPrize()+"; earnings =" + person.getEarnings());
      }
  }

  public void fillEarningsData (){
      personList.add( new Person( 1,"accountant",a,b,c ) );

  }
}
```

Comment: Рабочим языком Stack Overflow на русском является, как ни странно, русский. Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос.

Comment: Uhm... What? This problem description doesn't make sense. Did you mean *"Change a item's property when it's edited in a `TableView`"*?

Comment: Yes , if I want to write a new value of the program is to respond to my request

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514932/%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-tableview-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE